# HTML table behave like excel table

Tags: javascript, html, angular, excel, typescript

I'm working with an Angular project where I have a regular table.
Example:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to be able to select several cells without highlighting the cell data, only highlighting the border of my selection to able to copy it to an excel spreadsheet.

Obviously, onclick on an individual cell can be copied as well.

Example:

[image: select several cells]

[image: select one cell]

EDIT: since Scott Marcus, decided that he knows exactly what I was after, please don't provide any code.

And here's a clarification:

Is that possible? (Can I perform this change in Angular)

And how? (Is Javascript the way to go? I'm not sure. Since I haven't done anything like this before? Can you guide me in the right direction? )
Oh and please don't post any code! I honestly want to try myself.

Comment: Yes, of course it's possible. But, we are not a coding service. We expect that you'll do your research and make an attempt on your own before posting here. Then, when you do post, we expect that you'll post what you've tried, along with a ***specific*** question about your problem. As it is now, you're question is likely to be closed.

Comment: [Let me Google that for you](https://www.google.com/search?q=highlight+borders+of+table+cells+upon+click&rlz=1C1GCEU_enUS999US999&oq=highlight+borders+of+table+cells+upon+click&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIHCAEQIRigATIHCAIQIRigAdIBCDk4ODhqMGo3qAIAsAIA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am considering that you can work with js and css :

```js
  const cells = document.querySelectorAll('td');

  cells.forEach(cell => {
    cell.addEventListener('click', () => {
      toggleSelection(cell);
    });
  });

  function toggleSelection(cell) {
    cell.classList.toggle('selected');
  }
```

```css
  table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }

  td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 8px;
  }

  .selected {
    border: 2px solid blue !important;
  }
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: By the way, big thanks to Mohamed. I wasn't looking for code samples, but I appreciate it, brother.